# fetching data json to my list view

Tags: json

```
package com.example.velichamjson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://velicham.co.in/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=4:politics&format=json&Itemid=351";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_ITEMS= "items";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE= "title";
    private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";
    private static final String TAG_PUBDATE = "pubDate";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION= "description";
//    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
//    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
//    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
//    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
//    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray items = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link))
                        .getText().toString();
                String pubDate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pubdate))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_LINK, link);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PUBDATE, pubDate);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetItems().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node

                    items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);
                    System.out.println(items);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String link = c.getString(TAG_LINK);
                        String pubDate = c.getString(TAG_PUBDATE);
                        String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                        //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
//                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
//                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
//                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
//                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        item.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                        item.put(TAG_LINK, link);
                        item.put(TAG_PUBDATE, pubDate);
                        item.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        itemList.add(item);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, itemList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_LINK, TAG_PUBDATE,
                            TAG_DESCRIPTION ,TAG_TITLE}, new int[] { R.id.link,
                            R.id.pubdate, R.id.description,R.id.title });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

iam trying to parse json data it is a tamil news am fetching from my json data but it shows an error NO VALUE FOR ITEMS am trying more than an half a day any can answer where it goes wrong i dont know where it goes wrong anyone reponse me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the Incoming Json Data ?

Comment: http://velicham.co.in/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=4:politics&format=json&Itemid=351

Comment: the above is my json url

Comment: You have to iterate over the JsonObject correctly

Comment: can u explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE -** Using the JsonObject you can do as below

```
   if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonObj.get(TAG_ITEMS));
                // looping through All data
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject temp = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = temp.get(TAG_TITLE);
                    String link = temp.get(TAG_LINK);
                    String pubDate = temp.get(TAG_PUBDATE);
                    String description = temp.get(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

You can use the [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)
Like Below for your json data,

**NOTE -** I have not tested the code and you have to tweak it as per your requirement but thats how you can parse the JsonData using the androids JsonReader.You can look up the android developers page to more info.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(yourResponseStream, Encoding));
reader.beginObject();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("count")) {
            string count = reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("value")) {
           //Method to process the value object
           processValueObject(reader);
        } else  {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }


  private void processValueObject(JsonReader reader)
  {
     reader.beginObject();
     while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("feedUrl")) {
            string feedUrl = reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("title")) {
           string title = reader.nextString();
        } ....and so on
         //For array of data
        }else if (name.equals("items"))
        {
         reader.beginArray();
         reader.beginObject();
         //then use the same methods to get name and value pair.
            processReader(reader);
         //at the end dont forget to end your array and object 
         reader.endObject();
         reader.endArray();
         }
        else  {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: i tried but its not coming pls check out my problem

Comment: i dont know where  and how to write the  json reader code u given above can u explain briefly...thanks in advance

Comment: how to post my service handler class in stackoverflow am new to stackoverflow

Comment: No Need just use new updated code snippet in your code and test it

Comment: Accept it as answer if this helps you. So question can be close. If you don't know how to accept the answer [look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).